# Combining calls to multiple javascripts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to call multiple JQuery scripts using (a wordpress feature) wp_enqueue_script. The call to JQuery works perfectly but the second call to cufon doesn't. I'm not a php or javascript expert - could anyone lend a hand, is there a best practice method for this?

```
function my_init_method() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}    

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');

function my_init_method2() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'cufon' );
        wp_register_script( 'cufon', 'http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/simplefolio/js/cufon-yui.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cufon' );
    }
}    

add_action('init', 'my_init_method2');
```

Comment: Needs more detail. What do you mean by "the second call doesn't work?" In what way is it failing? Is the URL to the cufon script valid (try loading it like a normal web page to see)? Any error messages in the browser console? How about a link to a page that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Do you really need 2 js frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choice of way to deregister_script and enqueue_script is as followed (feel free to adjust it to your needs):

```
    function my_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_script ( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'jquery-cycle' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'hoverintent' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'superfish' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'jquery-validate' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'arras_add_header_js' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'arras_add_slideshow_js' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'ratings_scripts' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'wp-postratings' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'sharing-js' );
    wp_deregister_script ( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script ('jquery', '/js/mymusicplug.js', '', '1.4.4');
}
if ( !is_admin() ) {
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
}
```

As you see, my 'if ( !is_admin() )' is relative to the scripts 'output'.  I also deregistered with no registering - registering the script via wp_register_script causes total meltdown - and then enqueue the script file of which your combined/minified JS is located in.  This definitely works for me, with the result being a 143,000+ b JS file.  I know, it may seem like a hefty tag on a JS file, but with the simplification of things like combining JS in WP via 'deregister_script', it reduced my page by over 30+ HTTP requests for local and external JS.  The heaviest JS on my page now involves analytics in the footer, and AdSense code.  And still, I'm down to only around 10-15 requests.

Great Tip: Combine CSS too, 1 CSS file, 1 JS file, your page will fly!

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks mate, this was very helpful. The reason I was trying to en-queue all the scripts properly is that I wanted to implement the 'JS & CSS Script Optimizer' plugin so I don't have to manually combine all the files. Took me a while but I got there!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for here but it looks like you could simplify things by combining your two init statements

```
function my_init_method() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'cufon' );
        wp_register_script( 'cufon', 'http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/simplefolio/js/cufon-yui.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cufon' );
    }
}    

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
```

Also you should ensure that the `http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/simplefolio/js/cufon-yui.js` file exists and is accessible from your browser.

Comment: Thanks mate, it turns out I had misunderstood the deregister function - it was only needed for a script included in wordpress - as cufon wasn't that was preventing the script from loading. Thanks for your help!